# Vacm not honored by PySnmp agent

Tags: pysnmp

I implemented an SNMPv3 agent using example provided by Pysnmp, and added a user 'usr-sha-aes128 (code below).  However, VACM does not seem to be honored, as I can walk OIDs that are outside of what is configured for this user.  Any tips on resolving this?  thanks.

```
config.addV3User(snmpEngine, 'usr-sha-aes128',
    config.usmHMACSHAAuthProtocol, 'authkey4',
    config.usmAesCfb128Protocol, 'privkey4')
config.addVacmUser(snmpEngine, 3, 'usr-sha-aes128', 'authPriv',
    (1,3,6,1,2,1,2,2,1,2), (1,3,6,1,2,1,2,2,1,2))
```

The below should not have succeeded, since x.2.2.1.4 is outside the subtree under x.2.2.1.2

snmpwalk -v3 -u usr-sha-aes128 -l authPriv -a SHA -A authkey4 -x AES128 -X privkey4 10.11.177.39 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.4

`iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.4.4 = INTEGER: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.4.5 = INTEGER: 1532
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.4.6 = INTEGER: 1532`

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue with the latest released pysnmp. Which pysnmp are you using? I'm using [this example](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/examples/v3arch/asyncore/agent/cmdrsp/snmp-versions.html#multiple-snmp-usm-users) for reproduction.

Comment: I'm using Pysnmp 4.4.4.  Metadata-Version: 2.0
Name: pysnmp
Version: 4.4.4
Summary: SNMP library for Python
Home-page: https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp